# Populating a ListBox from search criteria entered into a TextBox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have posted this problem before, however, I think it was overly complicated and I didn’t explain it very well.  This time I am just using a simple UserForm as an example.

I want to populate a ListBox by entering search criteria in a Textbox.

I have three columns:

**Column A = Library Card Number**

**Column B = Pupil Name**

**Column C = Book Reference**

I have a UserForm:

**TextBox = txtlcn (for the Library Card Number)**

**TextBox = txtpn (for the Pupil Name)**

**TextBox = txtbr (for the Book Reference)**

**Command Button = cmdfinddetails (Find Details)**

What I want to do is change the TextBox ‘txtbr’ into a ListBox, so that I can see if a pupil has more than one book loaned out to them.  The process would be:

1. **A pupil enters their Library Card Number in TextBox  ‘txtlcn’ and
   clicks on Command Button ‘cmdfinddetails’**
2. **The code will search for that Pupil’s name and all the book
   references booked out to them.**
3. **The book reference(s) will be displayed in a ListBox.**

I have tried lots of things to do with RowSource but it always lists every pupil’s book reference.  Below is my sample code.

```
Private Sub cmdfinddetails_Click()
Set xSht = Sheets("Library")
        Lastrow = xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        strSearch = txtlcn.Text
                    Set aCell = xSht.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Find

(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Not aCell Is Nothing And txtpn.Value = "" Then
         GoTo libcardrefvalid      
     Else
MsgBox "Oops! That Library Card does not exist. Please try again.", Title:="We LOVE Reading ;-)"
txtlcn.Value = ""
        End If
    Exit Sub
libcardrefvalid:

row_number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Library").Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = txtlcn.Text Then
txtpn.Text = Sheets("Library").Range("B" & row_number)
txtbr.Text = Sheets("Library").Range("C" & row_number)
End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I would loop through the columns to find the library card number and matching results and store them into an array. Then put the array into the listbox.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  Sorry, I am relatively new to VBA, do you have an example of how I might do as you suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have already changed `txtbr` to a listbox, I was able to get your code working (looking up pupil name and adding all books referenced to the `txtbr` listbox) with the following additions:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'clears the pupil name (caused an error if not done)
txtpn.Text = ""
Set xSht = Sheets("Library")
        Lastrow = xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        strSearch = txtlcn.Text
                    Set aCell = xSht.Range("A1:A" & Lastrow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Not aCell Is Nothing And txtpn.Value = "" Then
         GoTo libcardrefvalid
     Else
MsgBox "Oops! That Library Card does not exist. Please try again.", Title:="We LOVE Reading ;-)"
txtlcn.Value = ""
        End If
    Exit Sub
libcardrefvalid:

row_number = 0
'clears the listbox so that you have dont have a continuously growing list
txtbr.Clear
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Library").Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = txtlcn.Text Then
txtpn.Text = Sheets("Library").Range("B" & row_number)
'Adds the book reference number to the list box
txtbr.AddItem Sheets("Library").Range("C" & row_number)
End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""
End Sub
```

I made a test userform and some mock up data and this worked for me. Hopefully you find it does so for you  as well.

Comment: Thank you for your time and quick response, USFBS that worked perfectly!  I've also learned a little bit more about VBA!  I wanted to give you a score on the 'This Answer Is Useful' thing, but I need a higher reputation.

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)